# Magento2 Get Order API data in custom section

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, help-wanted

In Magento2, when we call order API

```
/V1/orders/:id method="GET", 
magento uses *Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::get($id)* 

which is defined in the *Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository::get($id)*,
```

So My question is, whenever I use either of the classes to fetch data similar to API response(json array) it returns PHP Object, so how can I receive the similar response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory` by injecting it in your controller constructor. Using it you will be able to return a PHP object into JSON format

Check this:

```
protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct( 
\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

public function execute()
{
    $message = 'Hello World';
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $response = $result->setData(['Test Message' => $message]);
    return $response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't receive full info by only json_encode order info as some objects in array won't be filled(extensions attributes, etc)
I have used method that API is using to receive full json info

class: `Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceOutputProcessor`

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

$orderData = $this->serviceOutputProcessor->process($order, '\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface', 'get')

json_encode($orderData);
```